# Compare and find the closest datetime to given ending datetime

Tags: php

I have a list of data that I've retrieved and is ordered from previous to more recent datetime. I'm trying to loop backwards in this list based on a time and date I specify, however the date and time in the list won't necessarily be equal to the datetime I specify so I want it to find the closest datetime in the list then iterate backwards. Here's an example:

I want `2016-08-27 23:30:00 PM`.

List:

```
2016-08-27 22:30:00 PM
2016-08-27 22:30:20 PM
2016-08-27 23:29:40 PM
2016-08-27 23:29:59 PM
2016-08-27 23:29:58 PM
```

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: What datetime are you providing and what should be the desired output? Based on what logic? You need to explain it clearly with an example.

Comment: @Object Manipulator frankly speaking i'm doing an auction/bidding logic here...when an auction is end it will find the closest datetime with ending auction datetime....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push dates into array and sort it.

```
$array = ['2016-08-27 23:29:58 PM', '2016-08-27 23:29:59 PM'];

function sortbydate( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}
usort($array, "sortbydate");
var_dump($data);
```

If you want remove newer dates

```
function new($var)
{
    return strtotime($a) < strtotime('2016-08-27 23:29:59');
}
array_filter($data, "new");
```